# System.DllNotFoundException (denoting an unavailable 'libSkiaSharp.so') thrown when attempting to use the SkiaSharp library

Tags: c#, visual-studio, svg, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

The aforementioned exception is thrown at the line that reads `svgImage.Load(filePath)`, where `svgImage` is declared as an object of type `SKSvg` and `filePath` is the string holding the path of the `svg` file to be opened, with the exception message `'libSkiaSharp.so assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)'`.

I have the following `SkiaSharp` based NuGet packages installed: `SkiaSharp(v2.80.1)`, `SkiaSharp.Svg(v1.60.0)`, and `SkiaSharp.Views.Forms(v1.68.3)`. I am using `Xamarin.Forms(v4.5.0.495)` and the installed `SkiaSharp` packages all correspond to the latest versions supported by the installed version of `Xamarin.Forms`.

As far as I know, the `.so` file extension corresponds to the Linux based runtime libraries, which are irrelevant in my case as I am using Visual Studio 2019 (16.6.3) on Windows.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have just started using the SkiaSharp library with Xamarin Forms and had this exact same error. I double-checked my NuGet configuration and realised I had only installed the SkiaSharp package for the common project (and not for the `.Android` and `.iOS` projects) - it now works fine.

For VS2019 the steps are:

- Right click on the Solution in Solution Explorer
- Click `Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...`
- Select the SkiaSharp library from the "Installed" packages list on the left hand side
- Tick the box next to all of the projects, select "Latest stable" version (2.80.1 at time of writing) and hit Install

Answer (score 0):

I test on the `Xamarin.Forms 4.5.0.495` with `SkiaSharp 2.80.1`, `SkiaSharp.Svg 1.60.0`, SkiaSharp.Views.Forms(v1.68.3). The code below works well.

```
var filePath = "";
        SkiaSharp.Extended.Svg.SKSvg svgImage = new SkiaSharp.Extended.Svg.SKSvg();
        svgImage.Load(filePath);
```

If you still have the error, uninstall the packages and reinstall it. Delete the bin and obj folder. Try to clean and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/184002/error-framework-not-found-libskiasharp) post (originally) posted not long ago before this question, there apparently are, as of the time of this writing, some bugs/issues in the 2.xx versions of SkiaSharp. Using the last release among the 1.xx versions (i.e. 1.68.3) of the SkiaSharp library resolves the issue at hand.